How to fetch the current price of GM token from GMX?
I would like to fetch the current prices of GM tokens from GMX V2 via Node.js.
I have found the following info in here (https://gmx-docs.io/docs/api/contracts-v2/#getting-gm-token-price):
Getting GM Token Price
Returns GM token price and information about market pool: pool value, PnL, amount of tokens in the pool, borrowing fees and impact pool
Reader.getMarketTokenPrice
dataStore: Address of the DataStore contract
market: Market data of type Market.Props
indexTokenPrice: Price for index token of type Price.Props
longTokenPrice: Price for long token of type Price.Props
shortTokenPrice: Price for short token of type Price.Props
pnlFactorType: More information can be found here
maximize. Whether to maximize or minimize GM price by using either maximum or minimum price
I need help writing a Javascript code to fetch the current price of GM tokens. Currently have the following code:
import { createRequire } from "module";
import * as fs from 'fs';
const require = createRequire(import.meta.url);
const { Web3 } = require('web3');
const web3 = new Web3('https://arb1.arbitrum.io/rpc');
const readerAbi = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('./readerAbi.json', 'utf8'));

const contract = new web3.eth.Contract(
    readerAbi.abi,
    '0xdA5A70c885187DaA71E7553ca9F728464af8d2ad'
);

async function getMarketTokenPrice() {
    try {
        const price = await contract.methods.getMarketTokenPrice().call();
        console.log(price);
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error:', error);
    }
}

getMarketTokenPrice();

Error:
Error fetching market token price: Web3ContractError: Invalid parameters for method getMarketTokenPrice: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'marketToken')
at ContractBuilder._getAbiParams (c:\Users)
How can I fix the following error?
